# Except multiple exception with the same error doesnt work (or im wrong): Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok, simply i have this code, if the try block doesnt work, it goes on the except block (obviously) but
it goes only on the first except block, so like this:

```
                    try:
                        cover="https://t.nhentai.net/galleries/"+str(medid)+'/cover'+".jpg"
                        nhlim=bot.send_photo(chatId,cover,caption='Nhentai id: <code>'+str(pornId)+'</code>\nGenres: <code>'+str(genres)+'</code>\nPages number: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['num_pages'])+'</code>\nEnglish title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['english'])+'</code>\nJapanese title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['japanese'])+'</code>\nPretty (Short) title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['pretty'])+'</code>',parse_mode='HTML')
                        bot.register_next_step_handler(nhlim, nhen_sender)
                    except ApiException as e0:
                        cover="https://t.nhentai.net/galleries/"+str(medid)+'/cover'+".png"
                        nhlim=bot.send_photo(chatId,cover,caption='Nhentai id: <code>'+str(pornId)+'</code>\nGenres: <code>'+str(genres)+'</code>\nPages number: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['num_pages'])+'</code>\nEnglish title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['english'])+'</code>\nJapanese title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['japanese'])+'</code>\nPretty (Short) title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['pretty'])+'</code>',parse_mode='HTML')
                        bot.register_next_step_handler(nhlim, nhen_sender)
                        print(e0)
                    except ApiException as e1:
                        cover="https://t.nhentai.net/galleries/"+str(medid)+'/cover'+".jpeg"
                        nhlim=bot.send_photo(chatId,cover,caption='Nhentai id: <code>'+str(pornId)+'</code>\nGenres: <code>'+str(genres)+'</code>\nPages number: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['num_pages'])+'</code>\nEnglish title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['english'])+'</code>\nJapanese title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['japanese'])+'</code>\nPretty (Short) title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['pretty'])+'</code>',parse_mode='HTML')
                        bot.register_next_step_handler(nhlim, nhen_sender)
                        print(e1)
                    except ApiException as e2:
                        cover="https://t.nhentai.net/galleries/"+str(medid)+'/cover'+".raw"
                        nhlim=bot.send_photo(chatId,cover,caption='Nhentai id: <code>'+str(pornId)+'</code>\nGenres: <code>'+str(genres)+'</code>\nPages number: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['num_pages'])+'</code>\nEnglish title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['english'])+'</code>\nJapanese title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['japanese'])+'</code>\nPretty (Short) title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['pretty'])+'</code>',parse_mode='HTML')
                        bot.register_next_step_handler(nhlim, nhen_sender)
                        print(e2)
                    except ApiException as e3:
                        cover="https://t.nhentai.net/galleries/"+str(medid)+'/cover'+".psd"
                        nhlim=bot.send_photo(chatId,cover,caption='Nhentai id: <code>'+str(pornId)+'</code>\nGenres: <code>'+str(genres)+'</code>\nPages number: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['num_pages'])+'</code>\nEnglish title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['english'])+'</code>\nJapanese title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['japanese'])+'</code>\nPretty (Short) title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['pretty'])+'</code>',parse_mode='HTML')
                        bot.register_next_step_handler(nhlim, nhen_sender)
                        print(e3)
                    except ApiException as e4:
                        cover="https://t.nhentai.net/galleries/"+str(medid)+'/cover'+".tiff"
                        nhlim=bot.send_photo(chatId,cover,caption='Nhentai id: <code>'+str(pornId)+'</code>\nGenres: <code>'+str(genres)+'</code>\nPages number: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['num_pages'])+'</code>\nEnglish title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['english'])+'</code>\nJapanese title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['japanese'])+'</code>\nPretty (Short) title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['pretty'])+'</code>',parse_mode='HTML')
                        bot.register_next_step_handler(nhlim, nhen_sender)
                        print(e4)
                    except ApiException as e5:
                        cover="https://t.nhentai.net/galleries/"+str(medid)+'/cover'+".pdf"
                        nhlim=bot.send_photo(chatId,cover,caption='Nhentai id: <code>'+str(pornId)+'</code>\nGenres: <code>'+str(genres)+'</code>\nPages number: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['num_pages'])+'</code>\nEnglish title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['english'])+'</code>\nJapanese title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['japanese'])+'</code>\nPretty (Short) title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['pretty'])+'</code>',parse_mode='HTML')
                        bot.register_next_step_handler(nhlim, nhen_sender)
                        print(e5)
                    except ApiException as e6:
                        cover="https://t.nhentai.net/galleries/"+str(medid)+'/cover'+".eps"
                        nhlim=bot.send_photo(chatId,cover,caption='Nhentai id: <code>'+str(pornId)+'</code>\nGenres: <code>'+str(genres)+'</code>\nPages number: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['num_pages'])+'</code>\nEnglish title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['english'])+'</code>\nJapanese title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['japanese'])+'</code>\nPretty (Short) title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['pretty'])+'</code>',parse_mode='HTML')
                        bot.register_next_step_handler(nhlim, nhen_sender)
                        print(e6)
                    except ApiException as e7:
                        cover="https://t.nhentai.net/galleries/"+str(medid)+'/cover'+".bmp"
                        nhlim=bot.send_photo(chatId,cover,caption='Nhentai id: <code>'+str(pornId)+'</code>\nGenres: <code>'+str(genres)+'</code>\nPages number: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['num_pages'])+'</code>\nEnglish title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['english'])+'</code>\nJapanese title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['japanese'])+'</code>\nPretty (Short) title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['pretty'])+'</code>',parse_mode='HTML')
                        bot.register_next_step_handler(nhlim, nhen_sender)
                        print(e7)
                    except ApiException as e8:
                        cover="https://t.nhentai.net/galleries/"+str(medid)+'/cover'+".ai"
                        nhlim=bot.send_photo(chatId,cover,caption='Nhentai id: <code>'+str(pornId)+'</code>\nGenres: <code>'+str(genres)+'</code>\nPages number: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['num_pages'])+'</code>\nEnglish title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['english'])+'</code>\nJapanese title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['japanese'])+'</code>\nPretty (Short) title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['pretty'])+'</code>',parse_mode='HTML')
                        bot.register_next_step_handler(nhlim, nhen_sender)
                        print(e8)
                    except ApiException as e9:
                        cover="https://t.nhentai.net/galleries/"+str(medid)+'/cover'+".gif"
                        nhlim=bot.send_photo(chatId,cover,caption='Nhentai id: <code>'+str(pornId)+'</code>\nGenres: <code>'+str(genres)+'</code>\nPages number: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['num_pages'])+'</code>\nEnglish title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['english'])+'</code>\nJapanese title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['japanese'])+'</code>\nPretty (Short) title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['pretty'])+'</code>',parse_mode='HTML')
                        bot.register_next_step_handler(nhlim, nhen_sender)
                        print(e9)
                    except ApiException as e10:
                        cover="https://t.nhentai.net/galleries/"+str(medid)+'/cover'+".pict"
                        nhlim=bot.send_photo(chatId,cover,caption='Nhentai id: <code>'+str(pornId)+'</code>\nGenres: <code>'+str(genres)+'</code>\nPages number: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['num_pages'])+'</code>\nEnglish title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['english'])+'</code>\nJapanese title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['japanese'])+'</code>\nPretty (Short) title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['pretty'])+'</code>',parse_mode='HTML')
                        bot.register_next_step_handler(nhlim, nhen_sender)
                        print(e10)
                    except ApiException as e11:
                        cover="https://t.nhentai.net/galleries/"+str(medid)+'/cover'+".svg"
                        nhlim=bot.send_photo(chatId,cover,caption='Nhentai id: <code>'+str(pornId)+'</code>\nGenres: <code>'+str(genres)+'</code>\nPages number: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['num_pages'])+'</code>\nEnglish title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['english'])+'</code>\nJapanese title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['japanese'])+'</code>\nPretty (Short) title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['pretty'])+'</code>',parse_mode='HTML')
                        bot.register_next_step_handler(nhlim, nhen_sender)
                        print(e11)
```

If the first except doesnt work, the other except are not considered, but python neither give errors, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use the `for`-loop to simplify the code.

```
list = ['jpg', 'png', ...]

for item in list:

    try:
        
        cover="https://t.nhentai.net/galleries/"+str(medid)+'/cover'+ '.' + item
        nhlim=bot.send_photo(chatId,cover,caption='Nhentai id: <code>'+str(pornId)+'</code>\nGenres: <code>'+str(genres)+'</code>\nPages number: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['num_pages'])+'</code>\nEnglish title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['english'])+'</code>\nJapanese title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['japanese'])+'</code>\nPretty (Short) title: <code>'+str(jhen['result'][choosedNum]['title']['pretty'])+'</code>',parse_mode='HTML')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(nhlim, nhen_sender)
        break

    except ApiException as err:
    
        errorHandling
        continue
```

Answer (score 1):

If all of those exceptions are meant to catch a problem in your single `try` block (between the `try` and the first `except`), you should be catching *different* exceptions in each. Otherwise, only the first will matter.

On the other hand, if you're trying to catch an exception in the exception handler (and so on down the exception handling tree), you'll need to nest them, something like:

```
try:
    doSomething()
except ApiException as e0:
    try:
        doSomethingElse()
    except ApiException as e1:
        try:
            doAThirdThing()
        except ApiException as e2:
            andSoOn()
```